how can i make a function that adds a pre-defined input? Reactjs
im making a note taking app for D&D that, depending on the category you choose, it will populate with different inputs. so if you choose quest it will show a textarea for the description of the quest and a button that will add an input for a skill check and 2 other inputs for a pass or fail. the inputs are already grouped together as variables. its set up sort of like this
  const handleInputType = () => {

    const skillCheck = (
      <>
        <label htmlFor='skill'>Skill</label>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='skill'
          className='skill'/>
        <label htmlFor='dc'>Dificulty Class</label>
        <input
          type='number'
          name='skill dc'
          className='skill dc'/>
      </>
    )

    const desc = (
      <p>
        <label htmlFor='desc'>Description</label>
        <textarea
          contenteditable='true'
          spellcheck='true'
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="desc"
          id="desc"
          rows="10"
          cols="50"
          form="new-note"/>
      </p>
    )
    const passFail = (
      <>
        <label htmlFor='pass'>On Pass</label>
        <textarea
          contenteditable='true'
          spellcheck='true'
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="pass"
          className="pass"
          rows="10"
          cols="50"
          form="new-note"/>

        <label htmlFor='fail'>On Fail</label>
        <textarea
          contenteditable='true'
          spellcheck='true'
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="fail"
          className="fail"
          rows="10"
          cols="50"
          form="new-note"/>
      </>
    )

    if(category === 'quest'){
      setContentDiv(
        <>
          <p>
            {desc}
          </p>
          <p>
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {handleAdditionalInput(e, skillCheck)}}/>
          </p>
        </>
      )
    }
  }

i dont currently have any logic for handleAdditionalInput(), because i dont know how to add the inputs to the DOM in the way that i want to. it should turn the contentDiv into this
  contentDiv(
    <>
      <p>
        {desc}
      </p>
      // this is the new inputs that `handleAdditionalInput` should create. under the previous
      // elements, but above the button to add more elements
      <p>
        {skillCheck}
      </p>
      <p>
        {passFail}
      </p>
      <p>
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {handleAdditionalInput(e, skillCheck)}}/>
      </p>
    </>
  )

without removing the data already in the inputs.

for anyone wondering why im doing it like this, there are a number of different categories and each one reuses a lot of the same inputs. this way just seems better for readability and prevents me from recreating a bunch of inputs that already exist
